# python, print latex table, two backslash for single backslash in latex syntax

Tags: python

I have a data frame and want to print latex table.

```
fips                 state   sc_itpl_auto  
01 Alabama 0.859071  
02 Alaska 1.000000  
04 Arizona 0.864001  
56 Wyoming 0.833104
```

I use `pd.to_latex()` but the output doesn't conform to latex syntax.
It use `\\begin{tabular}` which should be `\begin{tabular}` in latex.

It always uses two backslash for one.

This is the result:

```
\\begin{tabular}{lllr}\n\\toprule\n  
{} & fips &                 state &  sc\\_itpl\\_auto \\\\\n\\midrule\n0   
&         01 &               Alabama &      0.859071 \\\\\n1  
  &         02 &                Alaska &      1.000000 \\\\\n2  
&         04 &               Arizona &      0.864001 \\\\\n3   
&         56 &               Wyoming &      0.833104 \\\\\n  
\\bottomrule\n  
\\end{tabular}\n
```

Comment: it escapes backslashes where needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `escape=False` option to convert it and you are fine. It is also described in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_latex.html).

For you example:

```
print(pd.to_latex(escape=False))
```

Should show the right results. Otherwise you can write it to a file with the same result.

Comment: The result is still the same.\\begin{tabular}{lllr}\n\\toprule\n{}

Comment: Yeah but this is fine just try to print it! Then you see it escapes the backslashes for internal python representation.